# how to submit and query values from web service infopath2010

Tags: development, infopath, web-services, custom-actions

I have a web service that takes a string parameter.

In my infopath form I have a dropdown list that gets values from the webservice.

I have another dropdown list below it that I'm wanting to populate with values that are from the the webservice, but from the parameter value of the previous dropdown list.

so, for example

web service =

[webmethod]
public List getStuff(string x)
{
   do stuff....

return results;
}

dropdown A values comes from webservice with default parameter of 'x'

dropdown A then submits values to webservice

Dropdown B values comes from the results of the submitted parameter to webservice.

I've tried creating two seperate webservices one with a recieve, and the other with a submit. then I created a rule on dropdown 'A' to submit values to the submit webservice, and then another action to query the values.  The problem I'm having is that I can not bind dropdown B to the submit webservice, and when I try to bind it to the recieve webservice I only get the values that are in dropdown A.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

-thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will probably need to do is create a hidden field and store your query value.  Then set the webservice query parameter to that hidden and then requery your data.